# How to make the MapView a button (iPhone/iPad)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uibutton, mkmapview

I currently have a map view in my app that is locked so that the user can't interact with it (i.e. scroll, zoom etc.), however I want to make it into a UIButton. The idea being the the can press the map view and it will call a function, the same way pressing a UIButton does.

I've had a look around online for ideas on how to achieve this but I haven't found anything yet. I tried making a UIButton over the top of the map view but I can't seem to make it invisible. I also tried linking an IBAction to the map view, however the option to link it  doesn't appear in the connections inspector (as I expected to be honest - shot in the dark!).

Is there any way to achieve this effect?

Comment: MKMapView inherits from UIResponder, so you could subclass mapview and implement touchesBegan:withEvent:.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a UIButton over the map, just like you tried before. But to make it invisible, change the button type from Round Rect to Custom.  This will make the button invisible unless you explicitly add an image to the button.

-Cheers